# Finding toolbox in Geoprocessing Package (GPK)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, toolbox, hexagonal-grid, geoprocessing-package

I have downloaded the tessellation tool for ArcGIS Desktop for making hexagon grids around a study area.

I only found a `*.gpk` file at https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=03388990d3274160afe240ac54763e57

Where do I find it as a toolbox (`*.tbx`)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If you have additional information that you need to provide then please use the [edit] button beneath your question.  If it is a screenshot then there is a picture button that you can use include that.

Answer (score 1):

The GPK file is a Geoprocessing package.

There are instructions on how to unpack it to find any contained toolboxes at [Using a geoprocessing package](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/sharing-workflows/using-a-geoprocessing-package.htm):

> When you open a geoprocessing package, the contents of the package
>   (tools, **toolboxes**, data, and associated files) are extracted to a
>   folder in your user profile.

Comment: i tried to do that but something is wrong and i dunno what should i do , its just appears as in this pic ( https://ibb.co/iaXEkb )